# How to fill in an incompletely filled in downspout on built up flat roof

Tags: roof, roofing

I notice that water pools up over a mostly filled in downspout fairly often on my built up roof.  The downspout goes maybe 3-4 inches deep before I hit a rough and very hard rubbery surface (I can't tell exactly what material it is).

I'm worried this semi-constant pool of water will reduce the lifespan of the roof.

My neighbor suggested filling it in with gravel.  Will that work?  Or should I fill it in with something else?

[image: Downspout]

Comment: Would you add a close-up (and better-lit) photo, along with an explanation of what we're looking at? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: So it's a removed downspout and you want to fill in the hole?  Never a good idea to remove a downspout. If it's partially blocked, you should unblock it completely.

Comment: I agree with jack, if you fill the hole with rock you just made the problem worse. Get a drain auger or a water jet and start clearing the pipe.

Comment: @JACK the house was extended a few decades ago and I guess this was where the previous exterior wall used to be - I tried unblocking it a few months ago and whatever it is a few inches in is very solid - tar-ish now that I think of it.  So I'm guessing it can't be unblocked.

Comment: @DanielGriscom thx you're right - will find a day to clear it good and post a better shot.

Comment: So there's no gutter connected to this?  No way to connect one to it to utilize the down spout??